# Use concat string within apex:outputlink inside visalforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a number of  hard coded link in visualforce page like below which works fine - (Note- this is used in custom Service cloud console component and usage of javascript.window.open is mandatory to display the link properly here.

```
<apex:outputlink value="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/,'_blank')" id="link1"> Google </apex:outputlink><br/>
```

Now, as I am chaning the code, to remove the hard coded reference of the URL and getting the URL from a LIST returned by Apex class

```
<apex:repeat value="{!LinksforAdmin}" var="lnk" id="theRepeat" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!lnk}" id="theValue"/><br/>
<apex:repeat>
```

Please suggest how to display the `<apex:outputlink>` using the `"{!lnk}"` value as above.

I am finding it difficult to append "javascript:window.open('" before the variable "{!lnk}".

Comment: Why did you switch from `outputText` to `outputLink`? Just stick with the tag that's meant to display links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<apex:outputLink/>` as follows:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!LinksforAdmin}" var="lnk" id="theRepeat" >
    <apex:outputlink value="javascript:window.open('{!lnk.urlName}','_blank')">
{!lnk.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
<br/>
<apex:repeat>
```

where `urlName` and `Name` are the attributes.